# Bing translator API integration

Tags: microsoft-translator

Here is the code I have implemented, here is my Bing application details

```
client ID =  pacific__tycoon, 
client secret == qCtCnigQ1afu8qi705ldOQ3IGy0rabMgHvVL+GU5Xww=
Name == pacificty--coon
```

I want a translator just like http://bunkerhill.com/, because it runs in iphone also with my website.

Are there any other solutions?

```
 <script src="jquery-mobile/jquery.translator-1.1.0.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" >
    jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

     $.ajax(
                {
                  url: "Default.aspx/GetBingAppId",
                  type: 'post',
                  dataType: "json",
                  data: "{}",
                  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                  success: function (bingid) {
                    return $("p,h1,h2,span,li,a,.xlatext,.clients").translator({ appID: bingid.d, languageListNode: $('#languages').get(0), callback: xlatDone });
                  },
                  error: function (x, err, desc) {
                    alert('madharchodError getting Bing ID: ' + err + ' - ' + desc);
                  }
                }
              );

    });
    function xlatDone(charsXlated) {
      if (charsXlated === 0) return;
      $.ajax(
        {
          type: 'POST',
          url: 'Default.aspx/SaveCharactersTranslated',
          contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
          data: "{charsXlated:" + charsXlated + "}"
        }
      );
    }

    </script>

 <div id="languages" style="overflow:hidden; font-size:smaller;" title="Language Translation"></div>
```